# Android emulator starts and then gets killed when starting in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, android-espresso

This is my first post here, even I found many problem solving answers here but for this I had no luck.

Android emulator starts and then gets killed after several seconds when starting from Jenkins, I can briefly see emulator widow, but then it closes. Same setup worked before, not sure what changed, I have tried to downgrade both Android Emulator plugin and Jenkins itself but no luck.
I am using Jenkins on local Windows machine, WIN 10 Pro, 8GB RAM. INTEL processor.  I have browsed all answers on the web but so far no luck, tried to reinstall Emulator plugin, give delay for startup, run with -no-window option(headles)...

This is log that I see:

```
    [android] Using Android SDK: C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk
    [android] Setting hardware properties:
        disk.dataPartition.size: 1000m
        hw.ramSize: 768m
        hw,gpu.enabled: yes
        hw.cpu.ncore: 2
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe start-server
    * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5815
    * daemon started successfully
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe start-server
    [android] Starting Android emulator
    [android] Erasing existing emulator data...
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android- 
   sdk/emulator/emulator.exe -skin 1280x800 -ports 5786,5787 -report-console tcp:5833,max=160 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop 
    persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_320_WXGA800_android-26_x86_RingCov -wipe-data
    Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
    HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
    emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5787) is outside the 
    recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for 
    the emulator. See -help-port for details.
    [android] Emulator reported that the console is available on port 5,786
    [android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
    tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5786 wait-for-device shell getprop 
    init.svc.bootanim
    [android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
    [android] Emulator was shut down before it finished booting
    [android] Stopping Android emulator
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe kill-server
   Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

This is different attempt when I got a bit further but result is pretty much the same:

```
    [android] Using Android SDK: 
    C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk
    [android] Creating Android AVD: 
    C:\Users\PavleD\.android\avd\hudson_en-US_320_WXGA800_android- 
   26_x86_RingCov.avd
    [android] C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android- 
   sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager.bat create avd -f -c 64M -n hudson_en- 
   US_320_WXGA800_android-26_x86_RingCov -k system-images;android- 
   26;default;x86
        Loading local repository...                                                     
        [=========                              ] 25% Loading local 
    repository...       
        [=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote 
    repository...        
        [=======================================] 100% Fetch remote 
    repository...       
        Auto-selecting single ABI x86
        > Process took a while, may wait for input.
        > <SENDING ENTER>
    [android] Setting hardware properties:
        disk.dataPartition.size: 1000m
        hw.ramSize: 768m
        hw,gpu.enabled: yes
        hw.cpu.ncore: 2
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe start-server
    * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5847
    * daemon started successfully
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe start-server
    [android] Starting Android emulator
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android- 
   sdk/emulator/emulator.exe -skin 1280x800 -ports 5706,5707 - 
   report-console tcp:5828,max=120 -prop persist.sys.language=en - 
   prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en- 
   US_320_WXGA800_android-26_x86_RingCov -no-window
    Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
    HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
    emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5707) is outside the 
    recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for 
    the emulator. See -help-port for details.
    [android] Emulator reported that the console is available on 
    port 5,706
    [android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5706 wait-for-device shell getprop 
    init.svc.bootanim
    [android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5706 wait-for-device shell getprop 
    init.svc.bootanim
    [android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 
    'running'
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
   tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5706 wait-for-device shell getprop 
    init.svc.bootanim
    [android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 
    'running'
    emulator: INFO: boot completed
    emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 
    2M.
    emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
    [android] Emulator was shut down before it finished booting
    [android] Stopping Android emulator
    $ C:\Users\PavleD\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform- 
    tools/adb.exe kill-server
    Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue but no clue why its happening. I can launch the emulator in command prompt. This issue happening only through Jenkins

Comment: Divakar Ragupathy, Any luck with this, I am still facing the issue and no one seems to know the answer.

Comment: Can you try launch Jenkins from cmd instead of install it. It worked for me. It means you download the Jenkins package and not installer and run jenkins service via cmd